# Multiprocessing module showing memory for each child process same as Main process.

Tags: python, linux, memory-management

I am using multiprocessing module of python and have some confusions regarding the same.

Basically, I store some data initially in the Main process, and that is around 16GB (main memory size) as shown in the top command. I have stored these data as global Variables.

Then multiprocessing is done on this data, and processed accordingly and differently accordingly.

Now I see that multiprocessing is happening i.e. all processes has its own CPU utilization, but the memory of all the processes in 16 GB each.. why so.?? Isn't it should use same memory that I send through pass by reference of global variables.. Please some thoughts.

The output of top command is as follows.:-

> PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
>   13908 admin     20   0 16.7g  16g  848 R 100.0 17.3   0:32.92 python
>   13429 admin     20   0 16.7g  16g 3336 S  0.0 17.3  15:06.97 python
>   13910 admin     20   0 16.7g  16g  848 R 100.3 17.3   0:32.94 python
>   13911 admin     20   0 16.7g  16g  840 R 100.0 17.3   0:33.02 python
>   13912 admin     20   0 16.7g  16g  836 R 99.6 17.3   0:33.00 python
>   13907 admin     20   0 16.7g  16g  796 R 100.0 17.3   0:33.06 python
>   13909 admin     20   0 16.7g  16g  796 R 99.6 17.3   0:32.93 python

Answer (score 6):

Each process spawned by the `multiprocessing` module is in a separate address space.  All physical and virtual memory that the original process had is at least *logically* independent of the new ones after the new ones are created, but initially each new process is an exact duplicate (well, see footnote) of the old.  Thus, each will have the same virtual size (16.7 GB) as the original.

Actual underlying physical pages are shared as much as possible, using "copy-on-write".  As the various copies run and make changes to their virtual memory, the kernel will copy the underlying physical page as needed.  Memory that is never written-to can be shared between all the copies.  So even though each process appears to be chewing up a lot of RAM, they aren't, really.  If you write to most of it, though—i.e., if each separate process changes most of the 16 GB of data—then they will all have separate copies, and use much more physical RAM.

The `multiprocessing` module does offer some methods of sharing data (see the "shared memory" section in http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) if you want them to share modifications (but then think about how the locking works; see the documentation).

---

footnote: There's one tiny difference between the original and the clone, after a fork or clone system call: the original gets back the ID of the clone, and the clone gets back the number zero.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the multiprocessing module as just syntax sugar around os.fork().

Now what is fork? When a process forks, the operating system creates a new child process with a new process ID, duplicating the state of the parent process (memory,environment variables, and more).