# Multiprocessing with large iterable

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two large Pandas Dataframes (1GB+) with data that needs to be processed by multiple workers.
I'm able to perform the operations without issues in a toy example with much smaller Dataframes (DFs).

Below is my reproducible example.

I've tried several routes:

1. I am unable to take advantage of `chunk`. The DFs need to be sliced into specific pieces on an index before each piece is fed to the workers. And `chunk` can only slice them to an arbitrary length.
2. Using `starmap`: This is what you see in the code below. Pre-slicing the DFs on the indexes and storing the pieces in an iterable. The pieces can be passed as small frames (or dicts) to the worker processes. This solution is not feasible at the sizes of my real DFs- the iterable never finishes being created. I've tried and failed using a generator/ `yield` for `starmap`. I would appreciate an example of a workaround if this is an option.
3. Using `imap`: The entire input DFs end up going to each of the worker processes. I was able to use generators/`yield` through an intermediate function that would slice the DFs and make them available for each worker without having a huge iterable. But the process was taking longer than if I'd use a `for` loop. The overhead of passing the data to the workers was the bottleneck.

I am ready to conclude that multiprocessing cannot be applied to a large data table that needs to be sliced before being sent to workers.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing

def df_slicer(df1,df2):
    while len(df1)>0:
        
        value_to_slice_df_by=df1.iloc[0]['Number']   #Will use first found number as the index for this process. 

        a= df1[df1['Number']==value_to_slice_df_by].copy()
        b= df2[df2['Number']==value_to_slice_df_by].copy()

        print('len(df1): {}, len(df2): {}'.format(len(a),len(b)))
        
        return[a,b]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    #These are large and will be pulled in from Pandas pickles. 
    df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3000, size=(100000, 2)), columns=['Number', 'Info_df1'])
    df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5000, size=(100000, 2)), columns=['Number', 'Info_df2'])

    iterable= [[df1.loc[df1['Number']==i], df2.loc[df2['Number']==i]] for i in list(np.unique(df1['Number']))]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool( processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1)

    for res in pool.starmap(df_slicer, [[i[0],i[1]] for i in iterable]):
        result=res
        pass

    print('Done')
    pool.close(); pool.join()
```

Comment: Pretty sure this: `[[df1.loc[df1['Number']==i], df2.loc[df2['Number']==i]] for i in list(np.unique(df1['Number']))]` could be a `groupby`... no?

Comment: Fundamentally, your `df_slicer` implementation is horribly inefficient. Almost certainly you can use `groupby` here

Comment: Is this linux/mac or Windows? On a forking system you can put the dataframes in a global variable and only pass indexes down to the child process. This avoids a heavy copy operation for the incoming frames.

Comment: @tdelaney it might be difficult to avoid the copy-on-write though... not sure

Comment: Depending on the operations pandas may release the GIL and allow parallel multithreading. I'm on exactly sure when that happens or if it changes on every odd tuesday, but worth a try.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If you do this with starmap, it will give a pickle error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I don't do this with pandas, but do with other things. Have a global dict, make a random key and `global_dict[mykey] = big_blob_of_data`. Then create the pool and all it needs is mykey. Should work for pandas I think.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm on Windows. I've seen in the docs that it makes a difference for fork/spawn. But I just can't move away from Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately on windows, all of the data to be processed needs to be pickled and sent to the child process. Its likely not possible in your case, but if the pool can do the data read from the source, that can be faster.

Comment: Honestly, trying to use `multiprocessing` on all but the simlest pandas operations is pretty much an uphill battle. Have you considered `dask`? It provides various out-of-core algorithms for Dataframes. it can also scale up to clusters if you need some serious horsepower

Comment: @tdelaney I thought of reading a pickle for each process, but it's 1GB+ for the whole thing. I even thought of pre-splitting the main DFs into their own pickled chunks to be read later. Thought I'd look for a way to avoid that.

Comment: If you do end up pickling intermediates to disk, `feather` and `parquet` are usually faster.

Comment: @tdelaney I was following the below example closely. This person had a 100GB+ dataframe but he made it work with by using chunk. Would you say my case is a non-starter as far as applying multiprocessing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240067/pandas-and-multiprocessing-memory-management-splitting-a-dataframe-into-multipl

Comment: Not sure. I'll review it a bit (dinner approaches).

Comment: Ah. Thank you for your time. Enjoy!  =)