# Share a dictionary of pandas dataframe across multiprocessing python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have a dictionary of python pandas dataframes. The total size of this dictionary is about 2GB. However, when I share it across 16 multiprocessing (in the subprocesses I only read the data of the dict  without modifying it), it takes 32GB ram. So I would like to ask if it is possible for me to share this dictionary across multiprocessing without copying it. I tried to convert it to manager.dict(). But it seems it takes too long. What would be the most standard way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: this is an important question when starting to do larger scale data science with python , pandas and mpi.

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/q/6832554/2650427

Comment: Maybe you can use threads instead of processes.

Comment: +1 You may be interested in this question here too [share-a-dict-with-multiple-python-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409610/share-a-dict-with-multiple-python-scripts/48494892#48494892) and the answer there [when-is-copy-on-write-invoked-for-python-multiprocessing-across-class-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084401/when-is-copy-on-write-invoked-for-python-multiprocessing-across-class-methods)

Comment: ...and there [multiprocessing-module-showing-memory-for-each-child-process-same-as-main-proces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369219/multiprocessing-module-showing-memory-for-each-child-process-same-as-main-proces)

Comment: Not a direct solution for your problem, but you may find an alternative approach here: http://dask.pydata.org/ Dask promises to enable parallel computation on dataframe-like objects larger than memory.

Comment: For which OS are you searching a solution?

Comment: @Darkonaut, MAC OS and linux

Comment: When you say it takes too long, do you mean that retrieval is too slow and your multiprocessing has to wait for each retrieval or that it takes too long to setup?  I'm also curious how big of a slice (ie.. percent of overall size) of the dictionary you need to take at one time and how often you need to grab the data (ie.. almost continuously, or is there significant processing taking place after you get the data).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best solution I've found (and it only works for some types of problems) is to use a client/server setup using Python's BaseManager and SyncManager classes.  To do this you first setup a Server that serve's up a proxy class for the data.

**DataServer.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from    multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
import  numpy

# Global for storing the data to be served
gData = {}

# Proxy class to be shared with different processes
# Don't put big data in here since that will force it to be piped to the
# other process when instantiated there, instead just return a portion of
# the global data when requested.
class DataProxy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getData(self, key, default=None):
        global gData
        return gData.get(key, None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port  = 5000

    print 'Simulate loading some data'
    for i in xrange(1000):
        gData[i] = numpy.random.rand(1000)

    # Start the server on address(host,port)
    print 'Serving data. Press <ctrl>-c to stop.'
    class myManager(SyncManager): pass
    myManager.register('DataProxy', DataProxy)
    mgr = myManager(address=('', port), authkey='DataProxy01')
    server = mgr.get_server()
    server.serve_forever()
```

Run the above once and leave it running.  Below is the client class you use to access the data.

**DataClient.py**

```
from   multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import psutil   #3rd party module for process info (not strictly required)

# Grab the shared proxy class.  All methods in that class will be availble here
class DataClient(object):
    def __init__(self, port):
        assert self._checkForProcess('DataServer.py'), 'Must have DataServer running'
        class myManager(BaseManager): pass
        myManager.register('DataProxy')
        self.mgr = myManager(address=('localhost', port), authkey='DataProxy01')
        self.mgr.connect()
        self.proxy = self.mgr.DataProxy()

    # Verify the server is running (not required)
    @staticmethod
    def _checkForProcess(name):
        for proc in psutil.process_iter():
            if proc.name() == name:
                return True
        return False
```

Below is the test code to try this with multiprocessing.

**TestMP.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy
from   DataClient import *    

# Confusing, but the "proxy" will be global to each subprocess, 
# it's not shared across all processes.
gProxy = None
gMode  = None
gDummy = None
def init(port, mode):
    global gProxy, gMode, gDummy
    gProxy  = DataClient(port).proxy
    gMode  = mode
    gDummy = numpy.random.rand(1000)  # Same as the dummy in the server
    #print 'Init proxy ', id(gProxy), 'in ', mp.current_process()

def worker(key):
    global gProxy, gMode, gDummy
    if 0 == gMode:   # get from proxy
        array = gProxy.getData(key)
    elif 1 == gMode: # bypass retrieve to test difference
        array = gDummy
    else: assert 0, 'unknown mode: %s' % gMode
    for i in range(1000):
        x = sum(array)
    return x    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port   = 5000
    maxkey = 1000
    numpts = 100

    for mode in [1, 0]:
        for nprocs in [16, 1]:
            if 0==mode: print 'Using client/server and %d processes' % nprocs
            if 1==mode: print 'Using local data and %d processes' % nprocs                
            keys = [numpy.random.randint(0,maxkey) for k in xrange(numpts)]
            pool = mp.Pool(nprocs, initializer=init, initargs=(port,mode))
            start = time.time()
            ret_data = pool.map(worker, keys, chunksize=1)
            print '   took %4.3f seconds' % (time.time()-start)
            pool.close()
```

When I run this on my machine I get...

```
Using local data and 16 processes
   took 0.695 seconds
Using local data and 1 processes
   took 5.849 seconds
Using client/server and 16 processes
   took 0.811 seconds
Using client/server and 1 processes
   took 5.956 seconds
```

Whether this works for you in your multiprocessing system depends on how often have to grab the data. There's a small overhead associated with each transfer.  You can see this if you turn down the number of iterations in the `x=sum(array)` loop.  At some point you'll spend more time getting data than working on it.

Besides multiprocessing, I also like this pattern because I only have to load my big array data once in the server program and it stays loaded until I kill the server.  That means I can run a bunch of separate scripts against the data and they execute quickly; no waiting for data to load.

While the approach here is somewhat similar to using a database, it has the advantage of working on any type of python object, not just simple DB tables of strings and ints, etc.  I've found that using a DB is a bit faster for those simple types but for me, it tends to be more work programatically and my data doesn't always port over easily to a database.

Comment: I should note that I have this implemented in a simple library at... https://github.com/bjascob/PythonDataServe